# Using Boost with roscpp (Catkin errors)

Tags: catkin, boost, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use some boost functions in my C++ ROS code, but running into some frustrating issues with catkin.

In my CMakeLists.txt file, I have the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(project_name)

find_package(
  catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  Boost
)
include_directories(
  include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${roscpp_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(exec_name src/exec_name.cpp)

target_link_libraries(exec_name ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

And I have installed `libboost-all-dev` on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine with `apt-get`. When I try to compile my project, however, I get the following error:

> CMake Error at
> /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75
> (find_package):   Could not find a
> package configuration file provided by
> "Boost" with any of   the following
> names:
>
> ```
> BoostConfig.cmake
> boost-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of
> "Boost" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
> "Boost_DIR" to a directory containing
> one of the above files.  If "Boost"
> provides a separate development
> package or SDK, be sure it has been
> installed.

I have searched all the files on the machine and cannot find anywhere a file named "BoostConfig.cmake" or "boost-config.cmake", are they something that should be included when I installed Boost through apt-get? If anyone could help me figure out why CMake can't find Boost, it would be hugely appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206973/using-boost-with-roscpp-(catkin-errors)/) by [Jordan9](https://answers.ros.org/users/22059/jordan9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2015-04-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you try to search for Boost in a separate find_package() call?

According to [CMake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html), the syntax is

```
find_package(<package> [version] [EXACT] [QUIET] [MODULE]
         [REQUIRED] [[COMPONENTS] [components...]]
         [OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS components...]
         [NO_POLICY_SCOPE])
```

Since Boost is a separate package, and not a component of the catkin package, I believe you should search for it separately:

```
find_package(
  catkin
  REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs
)

find_package(
  Boost
  REQUIRED COMPONENTS algorithm
)
```

---

Originally posted by [timm](https://answers.ros.org/users/6556/timm/) with karma: 376 on 2015-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2